# Using vector Initializer List Constructor with shared_ptr of Derived Classes

Tags: c++

I am trying to initialize a `vector` of `shared_ptr`s. Unfortunately the following small example does not compile:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived1 : Base {};
class Derived2 : Base {};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3}; // no error
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v2{
        std::make_shared<Derived1>(),
        std::make_shared<Derived2>()
    }; // error
}
```

Why can I create a vector of `int`s but not of `shared_ptr`s using the initializer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using private inheritance. This compiles:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Base {};
class Derived1 : public Base {};
class Derived2 : public Base {};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3}; // no error
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> v2{
        std::make_shared<Derived1>(),
        std::make_shared<Derived2>()
    }; // error
}
```